# Setting Compose Key in MATE

Tags: keyboard, mate, compose-key

How do I set up the Compose Key on Ubuntu Mate 15.04?

I tried **System -> Preferences -> Other -> Keyboard Shortcut**, but I can't find anything there.

Comment: In gnome-shell, is `Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Typing`. Or in `gnome-tweak-tool`. Or in a combination of the two, if you like me want the Compose instead of the (useless) Caps Lock.

Comment: @Rmano `Or in gnome-tweak-tool. ` Where exactly? Can't find

Comment: what I meant is that you have to disable CapsLock in `g-t-t` to be able to use it as a Compose.

Comment: @Rmano I use `CapsLock` for switching keyboard layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my machine (a Dell laptop) runing Ubuntu 20.4 with a Mate 1.24 desktop, the following works:  go to

System -> Control Centre -> Keyboard ->
Layout -> Options

Scroll down to Position of Compose Key; click on the black on-its-side triangle at the left.  Choose the compose key.  "Left Win" seems to me to be sensible since this key will almost surely not be used for other purposes.

Many of the other options (e.g. "3rd level of Caps Lock") are incomprehensible to me or
(e.g. "Menu") do not appear on my keyboard.